# How to override facebook share button css

Tags: html, css, asp.net

**How do i override facebook shaer button css ?**
    Is that any way to change the sharebutton css ?
I am using asp.net and i want to change or override the facebook share button css how do i do it ?

```
.sp_plugin-button {
    background-image: url("https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y1/r/LVx-xkvaJ0b.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}
```

How do i change the image of that share button i have override this class but not worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to this button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/
All you have to do is target the same classes that Facebook is styling to override them.

Example:
This is what Facebook is styling

```
.pluginCountButton {
    color: #6A7180;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

override with something like:

```
.pluginCountButton {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Edit: I see you've updated your question with m ore details. Facebook is using a sprite, so they are also setting the background position:

```
.sx_plugin-button_favblue {
    background-position: 0 -42px;
}
```

You need to override that too.

Edit 2:
Do this:

```
.sp_plugin-button {
    background-image: url("YourImagePathHere");
}

.sx_plugin-button_favblue {
background-position: 0 0;

}
```

Comment: How do i overide image of it?

Comment: dude change background-image. there is an <i> element inside. which have class `pluginButtonIcon img sp_plugin-button sx_plugin-button_favblue`

Comment: by adding more pluginButtonIcon img sp_plugin-button sx_plugin-button_favblue{ //my image path} is it right ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create one like this using Font Awesome as the unique dependency:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

HTML

```
<div class="facebook-share">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i> <span>Share</span>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.facebook-share {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 66px;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 0 1px 4px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Tahoma", "Helvetica", "Roboto";
    font-size: 18px;
}

.facebook-share span {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yu8j5bny/